Putting a polynomial into a multilinear form
Consider the polynomials in $x$ with positive-integer parameters $a,b,c$
p3[a_, b_, c_][x_] := Sum[Binomial[b, i]*Binomial[c, i]*i!*2^i*
  Product[x - 1 - 2*(a + b) - 2*j, {j, 0, c - i - 1}]*
  Product[x + 1 - 2*(a + c) + 2*j, {j, 0, c - i - 1}]*
  Product[x + 1 - 2*(b + c) + 2*j, {j, 0, i - 1}]*
     Product[x - 2 - 4*b - 4*j, {j, 0, c - i - 1}]*
  Product[x - 4*j, {j, 0, i - 1}], {i, 0, c}] /; 
  Element[{a, b, c}, PositiveIntegers];

Then p3[a, b, c][x] has the form of
$$
\sum_{i}{\alpha_{i}\prod_{j\left(i\right)}{\left(x-\beta_{j\left(i\right)} \right)}}
$$
where the $\beta_{j\left(i\right)}$'s are non-negative integers and the $\left(x-\beta_{j\left(i\right)} \right)$'s can be grouped together so that their respective $\beta_{j\left(i\right)}$'s form arithmetic progressions with difference either $4$ or $2$.
For example, consider p3[17, 7, 5][x]. It evaluates to the homogeneous sum-of-products expression:
(-57 + x)*(-55 + x)*(-53 + x)*(-51 + x)*(-49 + x)*(-46 + x)*(-43 + 
    x)*(-42 + x)*(-41 + x)*(-39 + x)*(-38 + x)*(-37 + x)*(-35 + 
    x)*(-34 + x)*(-30 + x) + 
   70*(-55 + x)*(-53 + x)*(-51 + x)*(-49 + x)*(-43 + x)*(-42 + 
    x)*(-41 + x)*(-39 + x)*(-38 + x)*(-37 + x)*(-34 + x)*(-30 + 
    x)*(-23 + x)*x + 
   1680*(-53 + x)*(-51 + x)*(-49 + x)*(-43 + x)*(-41 + x)*(-39 + 
    x)*(-38 + x)*(-34 + x)*(-30 + x)*(-23 + x)*(-21 + x)*(-4 + x)*x + 
 16800*(-51 + x)*(-49 + x)*(-43 + x)*(-41 + x)*(-34 + x)*(-30 + 
    x)*(-23 + x)*
     (-21 + x)*(-19 + x)*(-8 + x)*(-4 + x)*x + 
 67200*(-49 + x)*(-43 + x)*(-30 + x)*(-23 + x)*(-21 + x)*(-19 + 
    x)*(-17 + x)*(-12 + x)*(-8 + x)*(-4 + x)*x + 
   80640*(-23 + x)*(-21 + x)*(-19 + x)*(-17 + x)*(-16 + x)*(-15 + 
    x)*(-12 + x)*(-8 + x)*(-4 + x)*x

The code p3[17, 7, 5][x] // Expand gives the expanded expression:
-2768581095409860006276000 + 943994027469493936630800*x - 
 149697944309526908364720*x^2 + 14667497862393970765224*x^3 - 
 994671548312311638570*x^4 + 49540880455073938305*x^5 - 
 1875659092765152220*x^6 + 
   55077812834792653*x^7 - 1267294918092140*x^8 + 
 22896560965010*x^9 - 322878293760*x^10 + 3497819082*x^11 - 
 28246010*x^12 + 160925*x^13 - 580*x^14 + x^15

But suppose one wants to go the opposite route, by which I mean to forget the definition of p3[a, b, c][x] and to start from the expanded polynomial expression (like the latter), then proceed to find (if possible) an equivalent homogeneous sum-of-products expression (like the former, where it is a sum-of-products-of the $\left(x-\beta_{j\left(i\right)} \right)$'s and the $\beta_{j\left(i\right)}$'s form arithmetic progressions with difference either $4$ or $2$).
How can one achieve this?
My aim is to find a formula for p4[a, b, c, d][x] which conforms to the structure of
$$
\sum_{i}{\alpha_{i}\prod_{j\left(i\right)}{\left(x-\beta_{j\left(i\right)} \right)}}
$$
where the $\beta_{j\left(i\right)}$'s are non-negative integers and the $\left(x-\beta_{j\left(i\right)} \right)$'s can be grouped together so that their respective $\beta_{j\left(i\right)}$'s form arithmetic progressions with difference either $8$ or $4$ or $2$; and also conforms to explicit examples, like
p4[18, 7, 3, 2][x_] := -4320342548559582357548736000 + 
   1662054156267806454578208000*x - 299138656316488169592558240*x^2 + 
   33516630428588613233125776*x^3 - 2623968034551776285731728*x^4 + 
       152686740698465139941112*x^5 - 6855504875905429406922*x^6 + 
   243234494759468163361*x^7 - 6922588732903376380*x^8 + 
   159363606174946749*x^9 - 2975023649307356*x^10 + 
   44888502684386*x^11 - 541904089104*x^12 + 
       5134389578*x^13 - 36932522*x^14 + 190317*x^15 - 628*x^16 + 
   x^17;

and
p4[21, 8, 4, 3][x_] := 
  103186183991209740887417101826157081600000 - 
   45917368028969320058779916964505421568000*x + 
   9761002981879233777727633889621883148800*x^2 - 
   1320197598651543647286719378908065375360*x^3 + 
       127658115432381161053196484929234051904*x^4 - 
   9401201264506419996540184985671993248*x^5 + 
   548446542470173265813451627759716112*x^6 - 
   26026018366064838050921130582847960*x^7 + 
       1023566596632811306293953892324108*x^8 - 
   33815205487701302962097922840134*x^9 + 
   947593834806387270679180056401*x^10 - 
   22678562502910558312702776432*x^11 + 
   465601130990873072910334591*x^12 - 
       8218655339717011378691650*x^13 + 
   124752344116112860245825*x^14 - 1625093843805021062084*x^15 + 
   18085778309729089679*x^16 - 170676825373522506*x^17 + 
   1350397219108699*x^18 - 8809363705096*x^19 + 
       46227495717*x^20 - 187904462*x^21 + 556163*x^22 - 1068*x^23 + 
   x^24;


I can provide more explicit examples if needed.

Is the summation range of i, and the corresponding list of () are known? Otherwise, there is no hope.

@A.Kato For p3[a, b, c][x] - $0 \le i \le c$ and $0 \le \beta_{j\left(i\right)} \le 4\left( a+b+c \right)$. For p4[a, b, c, d][x] - $0 \le i \le d$ and $0 \le \beta_{j\left(i\right)} \le 8\left( a+b+c+d \right)$.

I see. You mean  () are bounded, but you cannot tell in advance  exactly which and how many integers appear. Then, your problem is still very difficult because you have to determine at least (d+1) x 8(a+b+c+d) coefficients just from a single polynomial. More information is needed.

I'll come back if I find some other constraint to make the problem more manageable
